# In Don't Starve: Reign of Giants is it common to spawn next to spiders?

Tags: dont-starve, reign-of-giants

Twice in a row this happened! The first time, with spider sacks as far as I could see, I counted at least 8 or 9 before they killed me, and the second time there were 4 or 5+!

Comment: 2 does not indicate a pattern.

Comment: I said two in a row, like 5 or 6 in total across my 11-14 worlds

Comment: Define "next to" were you under attack from the start or just close enough to blunder into them?

Comment: Did you fiddle with any of the world settings? If you tell it to generate a world with lots of spiders, then the odds of this happening dramatically increase.

Answer (score 5):

The spawns and the world in Don't Starve are completely random so it is possible that you got unlucky to spawn next to them twice.

Comment: Exactly. Many people don't know what "random" really means. OP is amazed that it happened twice in a row, in reality, it *could* have happened 1000 times in a row. Of course it's astronomically unlikely, but that's how randomness works.